# Octave - find number in vector (out of bounds)

Tags: find, octave, bounds

I have vector named STEV (it contains 12 numbers)

then I find the maximum value in this vector : `maxx=max(STEV)`

What I want to do next is to find the index of this maximum value (maxx) in vector (STEV).

So I do it like that : `i=find(STEV==maxx)`

But it seems that there is a problem in this line of code since I get the index out of bounds exception.

Pic:

[image]

Comment: Can you also show the code that generated this exception? I'm assuming you tried STEV(i)?

Comment: maxx=max(STEV)

i=find(STEV==maxx)   % INDEX OUT OF BOUNDS

the content of STEV is visible on picture

Comment: If you're sure you're not doing anything else in the code I can't figure out what the problem could be either.

Comment: For future reference, max outputs the index of the maximum element as well, you could also do this to get the index: `[maxx, i] = max(STEV)`

Comment: my guess is that you have created a variable named `find` so `STEV==maxx` is indexing the variable `find` rather than using the function `find`. Run `clear all`, and try again.